# react useEffect - fetch within a fetch - cleaner faster way to do this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a pokedex in react-native using the pokeAPI.
Each pokemon object contains another URL that needs to be fetched.

This is what i have, however it takes a long time to fully load.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentOffset > 1100) {
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchPokemon = async () => {
      const pokemonResponse = await fetch(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10&offset=${currentOffset}`
      );
      const pokeJSON: Pokemon = await pokemonResponse.json();
      const pokemonDetails: PokemonDetails[] = await Promise.map(
        pokeJSON.results,
        async (f: PokemonURLS) => (await fetch(f.url)).json(),
        { concurrency: 10 }
      );
       const pokemonDescriptions: SpeciesInfo[] = await Promise.map(
         pokemonDetails,
         async (item: PokemonDetails) => (await fetch(item.species.url)).json(),
         { concurrency: 10 }
       );
      let full: PokemonDetails[] = pokemonDetails
        .map((p, index) => ({
          ...p,
           speciesInfo: pokemonDescriptions[index],
           dex: pokemonDescriptions[index].id,
        }))
      setPokemonDetails((prevState) =>
        prevState ? [...prevState, ...full] : [...full]
      );
      setFiltered((prevState) =>
        prevState ? [...prevState, ...full] : [...full]
      );
      setCurrentOffset((prevState) => prevState + 10);
    };

    fetchPokemon();
  }, [currentOffset]);
```

anything i can do to make it cleaner/quicker.

I'm still pretty new to promises/async.

Comment: As your application will grow you will have bigger state so for its management either use Context API or Redux. When you'll start using them you can define your functions over there and have to just dispatch the actions from your component. It will make the code cleaner

Comment: For now you can detach the api calls as an utility function and reuse it as required.